# Why am I getting "empty results" when I create a Slack Histogram for my Test Project? How can I fix it?

Tags: vhdl, histogram, timing, vivado

I am currently working in vivado 2018.3.1 and I have to make a static timing analysis for a project. In order to keep my progress save I have create a basic Test_project to experiment with. I am a beginner when it comes to hardware design. Can someone tell me what I have to change in Test_project so I can get the results?

My project is written in VHDL. Hier is the code of test_project:

```
entity test_design is
  Port (
  int0 : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
  int1 : in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
  max  : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
   );
end test_design;

architecture Behavioral of test_design is

begin


max <= int0 when int0 >= int1 else
       int1;

end Behavioral;
```

When I try to create a Slack Histogram (Report > Timing > Create Slack Histogram) pops out a window saying "Slack Histogram Results are Empty".

Answer (score 0):

Timing needs reference points, start and end points. In a design that will be mostly register outputs to register inputs where both run of a clock-edge. (This does not have to be the same clock).

Other timing can be an input and output port towards internal logic. But as the tool has no idea what is 'outside' the chip it does not default generate timing for I/O ports. You need to specify external timing constraints to get those.

Your design has no clock and I assume you did not add any I/O constraints, which means the tool can't do its job.

Comment: Is there any good source where I can read how to specify external timing constraints? All that I am reading is confusing me more than helping. Is it necessary to define a clock to the test_project?

Comment: Most timing has to do with internal paths. So I suggest for chapter 1, you start with a design which has a clock and some big adders. e.g.  48 or 64 bits. Run synthesis and after completion open the synthesized design. Then use "edit timing constraints". The I/O constraints are more chapter 4 or 5.